# Any relation between degree of intermediate field and order of corresponding subgroup?

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

Let $\mathbf{K}$ be a finite normal extension of a field $\mathbf{F}$. For any intermediate field $\mathbf{E} : \mathbf{F} \le \mathbf{E} \le \mathbf{K}$, is there any correspondence between the degree of $\mathbf{E}$ over $\mathbf{F}$ and the order of the corresponding subgroup $\mathrm{G}(\mathbf{K}/\mathbf{E})$ of the full Galois group of $\mathbf{K}$ over $\mathbf{F}$?

I was working on an example of finding the Galois group of $x^4 - 2$ and all intermediate fields, and I wondered if this were the case or not. Of course the Galois correspondence shows that each such $\mathbf{E}$ has a corresponding subgroup $\mathrm{G}(\mathbf{K}/\mathbf{E})$, but I was wondering if there was any connection between the degree of the intermediate field and and the order of its corresponding subgroup.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is one of the key building blocks of Galois theory.

> (**Artin's Lemma**) For any field $K$ and finite group $G$ of automorphisms of $K$, the extension $K/K^G$ is a finite Galois extension and $\operatorname{Aut}(K/K^G) = G$.

For a proof see e.g. Proposition 70 of [these notes](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/FieldTheory.pdf).  As I point out there, it seems to be common to state the result under the additional hypothesis that
$K/K^G$ has finite degree.  In fact this is superfluous, although the proof requires some additional care.  My source for this was Serge Lang's wonderful *Algebra* text, which often presents classical results in sharpened form.

Now suppose $K/F$ is a finite Galois extension with $G = \operatorname{Aut}(K/F)$.  Let $F \subset E \subset K$ be an intermediate field, and let $H = \operatorname{Aut}(K/E)$.  Then we have

$E = K^H$

and thus

$[E:F] = [K:F]/[K:E] = [G:H]$.

So the answer to your question is *almost yes*.  However, a finite field extension $K/F$ is Galois iff it is normal and *separable* (the latter is automatic in characteristic zero and hence is sometimes deemphasized in undergraduate courses).   What you want can fail if we only assume normality: let $p$ be a prime number, let $K = \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}(t)$ and $F = \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}(t^p)$: then $K/F$ is normal, not separable and has $[K:F] = p$.  Taking $E = K$ we have $G = H = \{1\}$ and thus

$[E:F] = p > 1 = [G:H]$.

Comment: Thanks a lot - I just have one question.  Your above equality $[E:F] = [G:H]$ holds only if K/F is Galois. Isn't this also only true if $E$ is Galois over $F$, or is that not necessary? Does it still hold if $E$ is not a splitting field over $F$?

Comment: @Chris: $K/F$ being finite Galois is *sufficient* for $[E:F] = [G:H]$ to hold, as my argument shows.  (If $K/F$ is Galois then also $K/E$ is Galois, so $[K:E] = \# H$.)  To say that it holds "only if $K/F$ is Galois" means that it implies $K/F$ is Galois, which is not true: e.g. it certainly holds whenever $E = F$, no matter what $K/F$ is.  One need not assume that $E/F$ is normal (equivalently, a splitting field), and it need not be.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are talking about the Galois correspondence, I assume your extension $\mathbf K$ over $\mathbf F$ is also separable.

Hint: $\mathbf K/\mathbf E$ is a Galois extension, as $\mathbf E$ is defined as a fixed subfield of $\mathbf K$ by a finite automorphism group. This implies that the degree of $\mathbf K$ over $\mathbf E$ is the order of $G(\mathbf K/\mathbf E)$.

You should be able to figure out the degree of $\mathbf E$ over $\mathbf F$ from this.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if the original extension $K/F$ is Galois:

Let $H$ be a subgroup of $\text{Gal}(K/F)$. The Galois correspondence gives us an intermediate field $F \leq E \leq K$, where $E$ is the fixed field of $H$, that is:

$$
E = \{x \in K \text{ | } \sigma(x) = x \text{ for all } \sigma \in H \}
$$

It is a well-known result of Galois theory that an extension $K/E$ is Galois if, and only if, $E$ is the fixed field of $\text{Aut}(K/E)$, and that under these circumstances, $\left|\text{Gal}(K/E)\right| = [K:E]$

Thus, in the case above, we in fact have $\left|H\right| = [K:E]$, and so also $[E:F] = \left|G:H\right|$, where $G$ is the full Galois group of $K/F$